# How to define xmlns:ns2 from xml in xsd

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to create an XSD from an XML file.
The root element from xml has namespace as

```xml
<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
```

Now one of the sub-elements come up as

```xml
<SequenceNumber xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns="">1</SequenceNumber>
```

When I am validating the XML using my XSD file it is not recognizing the SequenceNumber element.
My XSD has the following definition

```xml
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:import />
```

How do I solve for this? Modifying the XML is not possible as I am downstream application receiving the file.

Edit: Adding the xml I am trying to parse. I have few other sample files. Objective is to create a xsd based on the sample xml's. The xsd would be used to validate the xml's before they are injested.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<POSLog xmlns="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/">
    <Transaction TrainingModeFlag="false" TypeCode="RETAIL_AUTH">
        <WorkstationID>25</WorkstationID>
        <SequenceNumber>1</SequenceNumber>
        <TransactionID>CA00001055</TransactionID>
        <OperatorID AssociateID="3333"/>
        <CurrencyCode>CAD</CurrencyCode>
        <ReceiptDateTime TypeCode="RefundExpiry">2021-08-28T21:32:55.000Z</ReceiptDateTime>
        <CustomerOrderTransaction OrderChannel="IN_STORE" TypeCode="Transaction" TransactionStatus="RETAIL_AUTH" CartID="CA00001055">
            <LineItem>
                <Sale ProductClass="Merchandise" FulfillmentType="IN_STORE" OrderItemID="2">
                    <Associate>
                        <AssociateID AssociateID="3333" OperatorType="SalesAssociateID"/>
                    </Associate>
                    <Tax TaxClass="BPTX" LineItemTotalTax="true">
                        <TaxableAmount/>
                        <Amount>52.00</Amount>
                    </Tax>
                    <Tax TaxType="STATE" TaxCode="CA-STATE-ON-ANY" TaxName="HST" TaxClass="BPTX" LineItemTotalTax="false">
                        <TaxableAmount/>
                        <Amount>52.00</Amount>
                        <Percent>13</Percent>
                        <TaxPerUnitAmount>26.00</TaxPerUnitAmount>
                    </Tax>
                    <Item>
                        <ItemID Name="Copper Amino Isolate Serum 5.00%">copper-amino-isolate-serum-5pct-15ml</ItemID>
                        <POSIdentity POSIDType="GTIN">
                            <POSItemID>769915150070</POSItemID> 
                        </POSIdentity>
                        <RegularSalesUnitPrice>200.00</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
                        <ActualSalesUnitPrice>200.00</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
                        <ExtendedAmount>400.00</ExtendedAmount>
                        <DiscountAmount/>
                        <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                </Sale>
                <SequenceNumber xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns="">1</SequenceNumber>
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
                <Sale ProductClass="Merchandise" FulfillmentType="IN_STORE" OrderItemID="1">
                    <Associate>
                        <AssociateID AssociateID="3333" OperatorType="SalesAssociateID"/>
                    </Associate>
                    <Tax TaxClass="BPTX" LineItemTotalTax="true">
                        <TaxableAmount/>
                        <Amount>6.24</Amount>
                    </Tax>
                    <Tax TaxType="STATE" TaxCode="CA-STATE-ON-ANY" TaxName="HST" TaxClass="BPTX" LineItemTotalTax="false">
                        <TaxableAmount/>
                        <Amount>6.24</Amount>
                        <Percent>13</Percent>
                        <TaxPerUnitAmount>2.08</TaxPerUnitAmount>
                    </Tax>
                    <Item>
                        <ItemID Name="Pore Delete">finisher-poredelete-30ml</ItemID>
                        <POSIdentity POSIDType="GTIN">
                            <POSItemID>769915130393</POSItemID>
                        </POSIdentity>
                        <RegularSalesUnitPrice>16.00</RegularSalesUnitPrice>
                        <ActualSalesUnitPrice>16.00</ActualSalesUnitPrice>
                        <ExtendedAmount>48.00</ExtendedAmount>
                        <DiscountAmount/>
                        <Quantity>3</Quantity>
                    </Item>
                </Sale>
                <SequenceNumber xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns="">2</SequenceNumber>
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
                <Tender TenderType="CreditCard">
                    <Amount>506.24</Amount>
                    <Authorization>
                        <ReferenceNumber>853598650372859C</ReferenceNumber>
                    </Authorization>
                    <CreditDebit CardType="mc">
                        <PrimaryAccountNumber Cryptogram="PARTIAL_DATA"/>
                    </CreditDebit>
                </Tender>
                <SequenceNumber xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns="">3</SequenceNumber>
            </LineItem>
            <LineItem>
                <Tax xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ItemTaxType">
                    <TaxableAmount>448.00</TaxableAmount>
                    <Amount>58.24</Amount>
                </Tax>
                <SequenceNumber xmlns:ns2="http://www.nrf-arts.org/IXRetail/namespace/" xmlns="">4</SequenceNumber>
            </LineItem>
            <Delivery>
                <Address AddressType="Delivery">
                    <AddressLine></AddressLine>
                    <AddressLine/>
                    <City></City>
                    <Territory TypeCode="STATE"></Territory>
                    <PostalCode></PostalCode>
                    <Country></Country>
                </Address>
            </Delivery>
            <Customer AlternateCustomerID="C-0000000039">
                <CustomerID>0016s000003ZC2KAAW</CustomerID>
                <EMail>
                    <EMailAddress>shi@deciem.com</EMailAddress>
                </EMail>
            </Customer>
        </CustomerOrderTransaction>
        <TillID>3333</TillID>
        <BusinessDayDate>2020-08-28Z</BusinessDayDate>
        <BeginDateTime>2020-08-28T21:32:55.000Z</BeginDateTime>
        <EndDateTime>2020-08-28T21:32:55.000Z</EndDateTime>
    </Transaction>
</POSLog>
```

Comment: Please edit your post and add your XML in its entirety.

Comment: Yes, it'd be much easier to help you if you include a [mcve] that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Also, what are you trying to achieve by writing an XSD based on XML over which you have no specification and no control?  The `xmlns=""` places `SequenceNumber` in no namespace, contrary to the default namespace given by `POSLog`.  There's a good chance that an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/234215) looms large here, so before going too far down the path of requesting help writing an XSD, be clear on what your high-level goal and greater context are.